# how to use angular groupBy and orderBy at a time

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am new to angular js.
Problem: I have multiple albums year wise. I am using accordion for the album view. I used simple query for albums without any group by and order by. Now angularjs groupBy is working fine. It's grouping the multiple year but I want year to be in DESC order which isn't working with angularjs orderBy. 
I have also tried this [solution](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/issues/57#issuecomment-65041792)
but to no avail.

Code:

```
<ion-list>
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in message | groupBy: 'year'">
              <ion-item class="item-stable"
                        ng-click="toggleGroup({{key}})"
                        ng-class="{active: isGroupShown({{key}})}">
                    <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown({{key}}) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
                    &nbsp;
                    {{key}}
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item class="item-accordion last-item"
                        ng-show="isGroupShown({{key}})">
                    <div class="col col-50"
                            ng-repeat="gall in value">
                        <a href="#/albums/{{gall.year}}/{{gall.album_alias}}">
                            <ion-item ng-if="gall.cover_image != ''">
                                <img src="{{baseUrl}}{{gall.cover_image}}"/>
                            </ion-item>
                            <div class="caption">{{gall.album_name}}</div>
                        </a>
                   </div>
              </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
```

JSON data in php :

```
[{"album_name":"test album","album_alias":"test-album","year":"2010","cover_image":"upload\/images\/gallery\/2010\/test\/Chrysanthemum.jpg"},{"album_name":"Orientation of BBA & BBIS 2010-2014","album_alias":"orientation-of-bba-bbis-2010-2014","year":"2010","cover_image":"upload\/images\/gallery\/2010\/Orientation%20of%20BBA%20%26%20BBIS%202010-2014\/IMG_5370.jpg"},{"album_name":"Corporate Orientation of BBA & BBIS 2010-2014","album_alias":"corporate-orientation-of-bba-bbis-2010-2014","year":"2010","cover_image":"upload\/images\/gallery\/2010\/Corporate%20Orientation%20of%20BBA%20%26%20BBIS%202010-2014\/IMG_5656.JPG"},{"album_name":"Convocation of BBA & BBIS 2005-2009","album_alias":"convocation-of-bba-bbis-2005-2009","year":"2009","cover_image":"upload\/images\/gallery\/2009\/Convocation%20of%20BBA%20%26%20BBIS%202005-2009\/IMG_3191.jpg"}]
```

Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages | groupBy: 'year' | orderBy: 'year'"></div>
```

(You can use any property which you want to orderBy)

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
orderBy filter not work with objects in ngRepeat. You have to use toArray.


        <ion-list>
                        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in message | groupBy: 'year' |  toArray:true | orderBy:min">
                          <ion-item class="item-stable"
                                    ng-click="toggleGroup({{key}})"
                                    ng-class="{active: isGroupShown({{key}})}">
                                <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown({{key}}) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
                                &nbsp;
                                {{key}}
                          </ion-item>
                          <ion-item class="item-accordion last-item"
                                    ng-show="isGroupShown({{key}})">
                                <div class="col col-50"
                                        ng-repeat="gall in value">
                                    <a href="#/albums/{{gall.year}}/{{gall.album_alias}}">
                                        <ion-item ng-if="gall.cover_image != ''">
                                            <img src="{{baseUrl}}{{gall.cover_image}}"/>
                                        </ion-item>
                                        <div class="caption">{{gall.album_name}}</div>
                                    </a>
                               </div>
                          </ion-item>
                        </div>
                    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.sortBy() and _.groupBy functions of underscore library

[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)